# LaTeX does not adjust font size

Tags: fontsize

Does anyone has a clue why LaTeX won't adjust the font size (I changed it to `10pt`, `12pt`, `5pt` but nothing happened):

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}% for control of list spaceing
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%coloring rows in tabluar
\usepackage{subfig}%for subfloat
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}% alignment: centered
\newcommand{\nodata}{\centering\arraybackslash --} %für -- in Tabellen

\begin{appendix}

\section{Cluster data}
\subsection{quarterly data}

%GDP
\subsubsection{Gross domestic product}

\begin{tabular}{R{3.5cm}R{3.5cm}R{3.5cm}R{3.5cm}}     %<--- damit geht es jetzt auch ;)
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cluster 1}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cluster 2}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cluster 3}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Cluster 4}} \\ 
\midrule

\rowcolor[gray]{.9}  Canada, France, Germany & Italy, Japan, United Kingdom, United States &\nodata &\nodata\\

  Austria, Belgium, Netherlands, Switzerland &\nodata & Luxembourg &\nodata\\

\rowcolor[gray]{.9}  Finland, Iceland, Norway, Sweden & Denmark, Ireland &\nodata &\nodata\\

 \nodata & Estonia, Hungary & Czech Republic, Slovenia & Poland, Slovak Republic \\

\rowcolor[gray]{.9}  Greece, Portugal, Spain &\nodata &\nodata &\nodata \\

  New Zealand &\nodata & Australia, Korea, Turkey & Israel \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}


%Plots

$\begin{array}{llll}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GDPClusterPlot1.eps} & \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GDPClusterPlot2.eps} & \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GDPClusterPlot3.eps} & \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{GDPClusterPlot4.eps}
 \\
\end{array}$

\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I run your code on my system (TeXLive 2011), except for the plots part (since I don't have your .eps files), I experience no problems with setting the default document font size to either `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt`. Note that `5pt` is *not* a recognized option for the `\documentclass` command. Are you maybe looking to change the font size locally, say for large tables? If so, try issuing the commands `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize`, and/or  `\tiny` immediately before the `tabular` environment.

Comment: OK, I'll post my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note that the options `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt` of the `\documentclass` command set the default font size for the entire document. Some document classes, notably the `memoir` class, recognize additional settings for the default size of the text fonts. However, no document classes I'm familiar with recognize the `5pt` option.)

To reduce the font size *locally*, e.g., just for a `tabular` environment that's too large to fit into the text block, LaTeX provides the commands `\small`, `\footnotesize`, `\scriptsize`, and `\tiny`. These instructions are *relative* to the document's main font size: the `\small` instruction reduces the font size by about 10 percent, while the `\tiny` instruction does so by about 50 percent. Hence, if you've specified `12pt` as the default font size and if you're using one of the "standard" LaTeX document classes such as `article`, `report`, and `book` (or one of the document classes that are based on the standard classes), text set in a `\tiny` group will we rendered at `6pt`.

To limit the scope of the fontsize change to the `tabular` environment in question, you should delimit the part of the document with a pair of curly braces, `{` and `}`. Hence, your `tabular` environment might now look like this:

```
{\footnotesize % change the font size
\begin{tabular}{ *{4}{R{3.5cm}} }
...
\end{tabular} 
} % end of scope of \footnotesize macro
```

Finally, if you encase the `tabular` environment inside a `table` environment, you needn't even use the braces to keep the fontsize-changing command local. Just issue the command `\small`, `\footnotesize`, etc. immediately after the `begin{table}` instruction (and before the `\begin{tabular}{...}` instruction, and the command's scope will end automatically at the `\end{table}` statement.