# Font size options do not work in tufte-latex

Tags: fontsize, tufte

The `Tufte-latex' classes default to 10pt type, and do not appear to recognize font size options:

## MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

  \renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=20.0}#1}}
      \renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=5.0}#1}}
      \renewcommand{\textsc}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\textsmallcaps{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\smallcapsspacing{\scshape\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}

\renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace{\labelsep}\textit{#1}}

\title{Sample}
\author{Me}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to change this? (I did see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45021/latex-does-not-adjust-font-size), but it doesn't really address my problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tufte class does not support the article/report standard options, as explained in the documentation (section *Compatibility Issues*):

> The following article class options are unsupported: 10pt , 11pt ,
> 12pt , a5paper , b5paper , executivepaper , legalpaper , landscape ,
> onecolumn , and twocolumn .

You can get around this limitation through the `fontsize` package but be aware that this may affect other aspects of the class (to be tested):

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

**WARNING**

The `parindent` option provided by `fontsize` does not work with `tufte`. This is due to the fact that `tufte` executes many codes \AtBeginDocument. In particular it executes `\@tufte@justification` which in turns executes, by default, `\RaggedRight` (package `ragged2e`). This last command, among the other things, sets `\parindent\RaggedRightParindent` and `tufte` sets  `\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{1.0pc}`. So if you need to change the value of `\parindent` you need something like `\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{<dim>}` (not documented) or, of course, `\parindent=<dim>` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: An interesting package! Are you the author?

Comment: Hmm... Yes and no... I am the author of the package but the core of the code is taken from `scrfontsize` and `scrextended`. I just served a plate in a way that I like but the real cook behind the scenes is, probably without his knowledge, Markus Kohm. For these reasons I find it hard to consider myself the authentic author of the package.