# Why the command \documentclass[n pt]{article} is not useful to adjust text size?

Tags: fonts, fontsize, paragraphs

I have to adjust text size and to do this I use the following code having read [this](https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/) article but unfortunately it seems there is something does not work so that I thought to put here an answer where I ask how adjust text size: could someone help me, please?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm,paperwidth=21cm,textwidth=17cm,textheight=25 cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's your desired font size?

Comment: @Mico I do not really: I would like compare some sizes but anyway I think that a good size could be 11pt.

Comment: To change the main document font size from `10pt` to, say, `11pt`, just change `\documentclass[10pt]{article}` to `\documentclass[11pt]{article}`.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't employ the obsolete `txfonts` font package. Instead, load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` font packages.

Comment: @Mico I just tried to use packages you mentioned but it is not possible to set up a size as 12pt, 13pt ect...

Comment: Note that `10pt` is an option explicity defined for the document class to set the font size. Only a few options like this are specified (and every document class has specific options). This means that you cannot use arbitrary dimensions here. If you want to set the font size to something other than provided as options by the document class, you need to set the font size in the document. Also see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45021/47927

Comment: In fact, only 10pt, 11pt and 12pt are supported (by `\DeclareOption`).

Comment: The `article` document class only recognizes `10pt`, `11pt`, and `12pt` as valid fontsize-related options. The `extarticle` document class recognizes five additional options: `8pt`, `9pt`, `14pt`, `17pt`, and `20pt`. Note that `13pt` is *not* a valid option for either document class. Question: Do you have to use the `article` document class, or might you be free to choose a completely different document class?

Comment: @Mico Okay, so a question arises spontaneously: if I use extrarticle then is it possible that my code has some problem since I already wrote 24 pages?

Comment: Sorry, but my mind-reading skills are absolutely worthless. Never having seen your 24-page document, I am in absolutely no position to speculate whether the document "has some problem", as you put it.

Comment: @Mico Well, you are absolutely right and unfortunately the only thing I can say to summarizing is that into the 24 pages are present substantially command as \begin{equation}\end{equation} or \newtheorem{} and \[\begin{aligned}\end{aligned}\] and other common mathematical commands.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro you can try... Worst possible result is that you'll,have some error, and so you will have another question to ask ...

Comment: @Rmano You are right... ;-)

Comment: Can't you just call `\fontsize` at the beginning of your document at top level? It should change the font size for the most part of your document. It would, however, not affect font sizing commands such as `\large` etc. inside your document. Hence, it is most effective if your document consists mainly of plain text without many environments and headings. The package `fontsize` can help you to "scale" also commands like `\large`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I just proved: if I put it into \begin{document}\end{document} at the top then the interline is really tight and if I put it outside the nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried, as Jasper Habicht suggested, to use the fontsize package https://ctan.org/pkg/fontsize?lang=en ? Changing font size is not so easy, unless you like a non-coherent document... Read that package documentation and try it!

Comment: @Rmano You are right!!! Jasper's suggestion works perfectly! :-)

Comment: @JasperHabicht I think you answer the question so that if you will write an answer I will surely accept it! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any document class only accepts a certain set of options that can be set as optional argument (between the square brackets) to the command `\documentclass`. The `article` class only supports a small set of options that are meant to change the font size of the document, and those are `10pt`, `11pt` and `12pt`. Other document classes might support more such options (like the `extarticle` class as noted in the comments), but still, each of these options is a previously defined option and, although it looks like it could work, you can not use any arbitrary value here. So, for the `article` class, you could do

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
Bar { \footnotesize baz } qux.
\end{document}
```

and this would change the default font size (also accesible via `\normalsize`) to 11pt and all other font sizes respectively. But you cannot, for the above mentioned reasons, use `13pt` in this way, for example. The above code snippet would output:

[image]

There are other ways to set the font size in a document explicitly, such as the `\fontsize` command (note that it takes two commands, the second meant to set the line spacing, and needs a `\selectfont` command after it). But using this command, you would only change the regular font size of the document (that is, `\normalsize`). So, you could set `\fontsize` at the very beginning of your document like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{11pt}{12pt}\selectfont
\section{Foo}
Bar { \footnotesize baz } qux.
\end{document}
```

[image]

But the text that is not typeset in `\normalsize` (such as the section title or "baz" in the above example) will still have the same font size set by the document class. It is maybe not that easy to see in this example, but "baz" is smaller here than in the example above where we set the `11pt` option to the document class.

If you want to change the default size of a document and also all other font sizes respectively, you can make use of the `fontsize` package. So, instead of the first example, you could also do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=11pt]{fontsize}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
Bar { \footnotesize baz } qux.
\end{document}
```

Which would output the exact same as the example where we used `11pt` as option to the document class. But you could also use arbitrary font sizes this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fontsize=13pt]{fontsize}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
Bar { \footnotesize baz } qux.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :-)